# getting database name from database log file header

Tags: c#, header, logfile

Can anyone help me to get database name from the database log file header.how to read log file(.ldf) header and get the name of the database from file using c#.log file of SQL database.

Comment: The LDF format is proprietary and I don't know of any libraries that can read it. The format can also change per SQL version. Why do you need to do this from C#?

Comment: I have to get two file location from user, one is .mdf file location and another one is .ldf file location.i need to check whether these two files are belongs to same database.if the user giving .mdf file of one database and .ldf file of another database i have to alert them.That's why i need to get database name from .ldf

Answer (score 0):

I would solve this by making it impossible to name the files differently, so you can always assume that the files belong together.

If that is impossible, you might be able to use [sp_attach_db](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179877.aspx) and try to attach the database + log file. It will fail if they don't belong to the same database. It's a blunt way but it should work.